# Excel removes leading zero from DATE when using text to columns

Tags: excel, date

I have cells formatted as date with type mm/dd/yy.  The dates display correctly while in the date data type.  Switching this to text obviously reveals the excel datevalues.  using text to columns however does not retain the format specified of mm/dd/yy, and instead always removes the leading zeroes and uses the full year e.g. 1/4/2019.  Is there any way to get the text to columns to interpret the format I actually have set?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I have a cell containing a date, and the cell is formatted as `mm/dd/yyy`, the value shown in the cell remains that way after applying text-to-columns. Perhaps you are really doing something different?  Oh, and Excel does not have a date data type.

Comment: Curious what vocabulary I'm mixing up here, what does data type mean to you?  To me it means the selection among Number, Text, Date, Fraction, etc

Comment: Maybe it's a techie thing. What you are referring to has to do with how data is formatted. But Excel itself has four data types:  Number, String or Text, Boolean, and Error.  (Other programming languages may have more data types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert a date to text using the TEXT() function.

For example: =TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yy") converts the date value in cell A1 to mm/dd/yy format.

Comment: Thanks Sammy, I was about to come on here and actually report that I did exactly this!  Sucks I have to use another column but whatever it works.